# Is this a Hipaa violation?

Tags: united-states

Is it a Hipaa violation to take a picture of someone in a medical office if they are not a patient. A person fell because of unsafe conditions and a picture was taken (that did not show face) to show the unsafe condition.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not a HIPPA violation. It would not be a violation even if the person were a patient, but the picture might have to be treated like medical information, and only given to those with a need to see it.